# How to get AppIndicator icons back in the top bar on GNOME 3.16+?

Tags: gnome, icons, configuration, indicator, system-tray

Ever since I upgraded from Gnome 3.14 to Gnome 3.16 on Ubuntu GNOME 15.04 I have found that my icons that would go in the top-right-hand corner go in the bottom-left-hand corner, is there any way to change this, remove the thing which holds them in their new place and put them back where they were before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, currently there is no way to do that. There is no option in any tweak tool or in the dconf-configuration.

I would say, the app indicator panel with the current behavior isn't the final design. Maybe in the future, there is a configuration option for that.

As a workaround you could try the GNOME extension [Appindicator Support](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/615/appindicator-support/), but you have to change the supported version in `metadata.json` to 3.16, as the extension has no native support for GNOME 3.16.

Follow the steps below.

---

### Without a previous installed version

1. Clone the latest version from [here](https://github.com/rgcjonas/gnome-shell-extension-appindicator/releases), do not use zip files or release tarballs., eg

   ```
   mkdir -p ~/src
   cd ~/src
   git clone https://github.com/rgcjonas/gnome-shell-extension-appindicator.git
   ```
2. Build and install

   ```
   cd gnome-shell-extension-appindicator
   make
   ln -s ~/src/gnome-shell-extension-appindicator ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/appindicatorsupport@rgcjonas.gmail.com
   ```
3. Follow the steps in **With a previous installed version**

---

### With a previous installed version

1. Open the configuration file `metadata.json`

   ```
   nano ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/appindicatorsupport@rgcjonas.gmail.com/metadata.json
   ```

   and add `3.16` in the `shell-version`

   ```
   shell-version": ["3.8", "3.10", "3.12", "3.14", "3.16"]
   ```
2. Restart the shell via <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `r` followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Use the GNOME Tweak Tool to activate the extension

   [image]
4. In my case, only <kbd>Show in panel</kbd> works

   [image]

   [image]

Comment: I already have that extension installed, where is this `.json` file located?

Comment: Also is the space necessary or just a typo before the `3.16` in your example?

Comment: Sorry, no. It was a typo, I'm on mobile :)

Comment: Ok, so where would I make this feature request? Gnome Tweak Tool? Gnome Shell? Both? :)

Comment: For the extension? Directly on GitHub. The link is on the extension page.

Comment: No, I meant to suggest it as a feature to have it like it was in Gnome 3.14 with the icons on the top right, and not the bottom left. You know, an optional feature... But I will probably also do it for the extension, although there is word around that that extension is no longer being maintained.

Comment: All this gnome stuff...  O:-)

Comment: @ParanoidPanda I believe that makes no sense. They pursue their own design.

Comment: I would suggest it as an option in Gnome Tweak Tool for people who don't want it and want to switch back. Anyway, I have now done so. :)

Comment: As this extension seems to no longer support the latest versions of GNOME nor any longer be maintained perhaps it would be better to have [this](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1031/topicons/) one in the answer?

Answer (score 5):

As of Ocbober 2016, Using Ubuntu 16.04 with gnome-shell, you can use the extension at

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1031/topicons/

It achieves the desired result.

[image: webpage printscreen]