# DropBox icon not appearing in AppIndicator section top right in GNOME 3.16

Tags: gnome, 15.04, indicator, dropbox

I have followed what [@A.B. said here](https://askubuntu.com/a/657744/364819), and it worked for Shutter, Skype, and Steam, however it seems to have no affect on the DropBox icon, how come? And is there any fix for this?

---

**OS Information:**

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
Codename:   vivid
Flavour: GNOME
GNOME Version: 3.16
```

Comment: Yep. Probably a known (and ignored) bug somewhere. https://github.com/rgcjonas/gnome-shell-extension-appindicator/issues/40

Comment: @Rmano than write an answer =)

Comment: @A.B. done, although I am not sure at all this is the same case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In oldest version of gnome-shell, like the 3.10 that come with Ubuntu Trusty, the icon is there on startup but it is prone to disappear as soon as the lock screen kicks in, the computer resumes from suspend, or the phase of the moon changes too much.

In my case using `dropbox stop` and then `dropbox start` make the icon reappear. For a while, at least.

I reported [a bug for appindicator](https://github.com/rgcjonas/gnome-shell-extension-appindicator/issues/40), but giving the comments there, it is not clear if it's a bug in the extension, gnome, dropbox or whatever.

That could be related to this problem as well as not; this answer is just a wild shot.